# Using jq in AWS buildspec before authentication - best practice?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild, dockerhub

My AWS CodeBuild buildspec.yml currently looks like this:

1. docker pull jq
2. PASSWORD=`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value ... | docker run jq '.password'`
3. docker login
4. (pull actual images and proceed with build)

In other words, in order to login to Docker I need the account password from Secrets Manager, and in order to parse the JSON-formatted secret to isolate the password I need `jq`, and historically `jq` has come from a `docker pull`

But now with rate limits on unauthenticated requests, that initial pull fails.

What is the more standard way of going about this? Install `jq` with `apt-get` or similar? Parse the JSON using some other tool that would already be available? Don't try to store JSON-formatted secrets? Something else?

I don't want to go solve this in my own unique way if there is a standard practice out there I just haven't discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codebuild can directly pass a secret as an environment variable. You don't need to use the cli command to retrieve the secret.

```
env:
    secrets-manager: 
        key: secret-id:json-key:version-stage:version-id
```

Check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.env.secrets-manager)

Comment: This is absolutely lovely; thank you! Relevant docs for CloudFormation are here: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codebuild-project-environmentvariable.html

Answer (score 4):

`jq` is **already available** in standard CodeBuild images based on Amazon Linux 2 and Ubuntu. You can check what packages are available by inspecting `Dockerfiles` for these images:

- [Amazon Linux 2 Standard 3.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/al2/x86_64/standard/3.0/Dockerfile)
- [Ubuntu Standard 4.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/ubuntu/standard/4.0/Dockerfile)

Thus you shouldn't need to install it yourself, unless maybe you are using non-standard CodeBuild image.